# how do I set the secure attribute on the google translate cookie

Tags: cookies, google-translate

After each PCI scan of our website, I have to go in to the scan results and add a dispute for the issue "Cookie does not use the Secure attribute", a PCI failing condition, for the Google Translate cookie. Is there any way to set this attribute for the Google Translate cookie? I have searched online but so far have found nothing, other than an old GitHub issue with Chrome 78 where one of the posters mentions Google Translate, but only to say that it was experiencing the same issue as the other posters.

Server is IIS 10 on Windows Server 2016.

Here's what I have tried. I put the following into web.config, but the outgoing cookie still does not have the Secure attribute.

```
<outboundRules rewriteBeforeCache="true">
    <rule name="Add Secure" preCondition="No Secure" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
        <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Set_Cookie" pattern="*" negate="false" />
        <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:0}; secure" />
        <conditions />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Add HttpOnly" preCondition="No HttpOnly" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
        <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Set_Cookie" pattern="*" negate="false" />
        <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:0}; HttpOnly" />
        <conditions />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Add SameSite" preCondition="No SameSite" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
        <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Set_Cookie" pattern="*" negate="false" />
        <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:0}; SameSite=None" />
        <conditions />
    </rule>
    <preConditions>
        <preCondition name="No Secure">
            <add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern="." />
            <add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern="; secure" negate="true" />
        </preCondition>
        <preCondition name="No HttpOnly">
            <add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern="." />
            <add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern="; HttpOnly" negate="true" />
        </preCondition>
        <preCondition name="No SameSite">
            <add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern="." />
            <add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern="; SameSite" negate="true" />
        </preCondition>
    </preConditions>
</outboundRules>
```

Comment: Using the above rules, I am now correctly setting the `HttpOnly` and `SameSite=None` attributes to the `googtrans` cookie. But for some reason, it still is not applying the `secure` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this after two days of fruitless searching and trial and error experimentation. So I thought I would post the solution here to save someone else the headache. The problem, discovered by using Failed Request Tracing to see what URL Rewrite was doing (or not doing, as it turned out), was that when evaluating the preconditions, IIS evaluates *all* of the cookies as one string. So if even *one* of the cookies already had the secure attribute, the precondition would fail and *none* of the other cookies would get the secure attribute set. This seems to be a bug in IIS, as the Rewrite rules themselves act on each cookie separately. Anyway, the solution was to ditch the preconditions entirely. The part I don't like about this "solution", which really makes it a workaround, is that if a cookie already has the `Secure` attribute, it gets a second one. But browsers seem to ignore that, and now call all of the cookies Secure.